# My table in xslt doesn't work

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XML file which looks like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

<root text="Récapitulatif des bug MD 360">
<list day="2016-11-15">
<item text="3988 (K2) : [MozillaMD] Plantage vidéo de localisation prise OBD" severite="K2" importance="Anomalie" status="RESOLVED" etat=" WORKSFORME" date="20Thu Nov 17 10:52:52 2016"></item>
<item text="4853 (K2) : Profil Midas : Menu de configuration du serveur atelier" severite="K2" importance="Evolution" status="ASSIGNED" etat=" FIXED" date="20Thu Nov 17 10:52:52 2016"></item>
<item text="4991 (K3) : ECU screen affiché au lieu de ECU Fault screen" severite="K3" importance="Evolution" status="RESOLVED" etat=" FIXED" date="20Thu Nov 17 10:52:52 2016"></item>
<item text="4992 (K3) : Bouton &quot;Voir tous les calculateurs&quot; à supprimer dans Express Diag view" severite="K3" importance="Evolution" status="RESOLVED" etat=" WONTFIX" date="20Thu Nov 17 10:52:52 2016"></item>
<item text="4993 (K3) : Zone clickable buton trop grande sur ECU fault screen" severite="K3" importance="Evolution" status="NEW" etat=" FIXED" date="20Thu Nov 17 10:52:52 2016"></item>
<item text="4994 (K3) : Mauvaises résolutions des icones du portail 0" severite="K3" importance="Evolution" status="RESOLVED" etat=" FIXED" date="20Thu Nov 17 10:52:52 2016"></item>
</list>
</root>
```

My .xsl is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="list">
<body>
<p><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr bgcolor="#009900"> 
  <td>K1</td> 
  <td>K2</td>
  <td>K3</td>
  <td>K4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(item[@severite='K1'])"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(item[@severite='K2'])"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(item[@severite='K3'])"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(item[@severite='K4'])"/></td>
</tr>
</table></p>
</body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output is just a line : K1 K2 K3 K4  57 126 103 13
I have correct values, but I don't have my table and I can't understand why.

Comment: What tool are you using 1) to do the transformation and 2) to look at the result?

Comment: I use Notepad++ and my browser (Internet Explorer because of work) to see the result.

Comment: The result of this transformation is not a single line of text. In IE, have a look at the _source code_ of what the browser displays as the result. Does your real input document document look exactly like the one you show in the question? Did you perhaps omit a namespace declaration?

Comment: Yes the output is exactly the same as I show in my question. Apparently IE console says me that "Only one root element is allowed". But my .xml looks right for me.

Comment: I just reoppenned it and it works...

Comment: _"Yes the output is exactly the same as I show in my question"_ - I was talking about the input document, not the output. _"Apparently IE console says me that 'Only one root element is allowed'"_ - which most likely means that your input document has several `list` elements. In this context "root element" does not mean an element with the name "root", it means the outermost element of a document. That reopening the document makes the problem go away without changing the input document is a bit confusing.